# Can time series forecasting be done without splitting the data into train/test sets?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, unsupervised-learning

The data is of monthly average rainfall for a specific region for the past 13 years (156 data points). What is the best way of splitting it into train/test sets?

I thought of selecting first 12 years as training set and 13th year as the test set. but was wondering whether there can be a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's better, but there is a *different* approach if you're using state-space model (SSM) representations of your time series models. In this case, you don't need to pick consecutive observations or periods in the beginning/end of the sample. You simply get a random set of observations for the holdout sample. SSM will be able to imply the dependent variable for the holdout sample - where you set the dependent variable to NA (missing) - regardless of where the observations are. So, you can calculate your predictive performance metrics comparing the implied values with actuals. This liberates your from a very restrictive train/holdout arrangement that you mentioned in your question.